# Elasticsearch, how to make a query that matches strings with spaces

Tags: elasticsearch

I am in learning process of ElasticSearch and having hard time matching certain cases.

For example I have product name: "SkyProdigy 130" and I am trying to write a query that will match this product name when someone types "sky prodigy". Also, another example for the manufacturer "Magpul" I would like to be able to match even if someone type "mag pul", etc.

I have managed to make this work with fuzzy query, but I am looking for a more organic way to achieve this through analyzers and correct mappings.

Can someone recommend the best approach for this case?

Comment: Even the most basic analyzer would tokenize a string at whitespaces and that is how you start with your data processing ideally. But you could go about using a custom analyzer which uses a whitespace tokenizer and Ngram filters so that if you pass "SkyProdigy 130", it gets split into "SkyProdigy" and "130" and then generates tokens like sky, kyp, ypr, pro, rod, etc. This could be one approach where you control the ngram size.

Comment: Thank you Varun, I have actually discovered just that. I have created a Ngram filter with min size 2 and max size 8, and its working as expected. I have also read that shingles can help with this case, too.

Comment: Glad you discovered it :) Shingles are a different usecase though :)